# Showing that the integral operator $Ku(x):=\int_{A}k(x,y)u(y)dy$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator if $k\in L^2(A^2)$ for $A\subset\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $k\in L^2(A^2;\mathbb{C})$. I am trying to understand how we can conclude that the integral operator $K$ defined to act on $L^2(A;\mathbb{C})$ by $Ku(x) := \int_Ak(x,y)u(y) \mathrm dy$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, namely that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \|Ke_i\|_{L^2(A)}^2 < \infty$, if $\{e_j\}$ is a Hilbert basis for $L^2(A;\mathbb{C})$. It is clear to me that the product functions $(e_ie_j)(x,y) := e_i(x)e_j(y)$ form a Hilbert basis for $L^2(A^2;\mathbb{C})$ and that the kernel function $k(.,.)$ is an $L^2(A;\mathbb{C})$ function for almost every fixed $x,y$, meaning that $k(.,y), k(x,.)\in L^2(A;\mathbb{C})$ for almost every $x,y\in A$.

My current problem is that 1.) I don't know what I should compute $\|Ke_i\|_{L^2(A)}$ to be and/or 2.) the only upper bound I can find for the terms $\|Ke_i\|_{L^2(A)}$ is $k$'s $L^2$ norm, $\int_{A^2}|k(x,y)|^2dxdy$. To be more precise,

we have

$$\|Ke_i\|_{L^2(A)}^2 = \int_A\left|\int_Ak(x,y)e_i(y) \mathrm dy\right|^2 \mathrm dx$$

and while we can surely represent

$$k = \sum_{j,l=1}^\infty \langle k,e_je_l\rangle e_je_l$$

I don't know how to use this, since the extra $e_j,e_l$ terms are not conjugated, so we just get

$$\|Ke_i\|_{L^2(A)}^2 = \int_A\left|\sum_{j,l=1}^\infty\langle k,e_je_l\rangle \int_Ak(x,y)e_i(y)e_j(x)e_l(y) \mathrm dy\right|^2 \mathrm dx$$

and so I can't see any way to use the orthonormality of the $e_i$s. What should I do?

Comment: I believe you're overthinking this. By the assumption $k\in L^2(A^2;\mathbb C)$, we have that $K$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator with $\|K\|_{\mathrm{HS}}=\|k\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: $k=\sum K(\bar e_n)\otimes e_n$ and the $K(\bar e_n)\otimes e_n$s are pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: @Math1000 What? I mean that a bounded linear operator $A\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ is **by definition** a Hilbert-Schmidt operator if and only if  $\sum_{i}||Ae_i||^2 < \infty$ for $\{e_i\}$ the O.N.B. of $H$. Thus, if we are given such a kernel $k\in L^2(A^2;\mathbb{C})$, we have to show that the sum $\sum_{i}||Ke_i||^2$ of the operator $K$ converges. I don't see any other way of concluding the Hilbert-Schmidt property for $K$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Okay, and how should I use this?

Comment: Allow me to rephrase - while $\|K\|_{\mathrm H} = \|k\|_{L^2}$ does not follow immediately, the proof is rather straightforward. See here for example: https://matthewhr.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/hilbert-schmidt-theory.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$$k=∑K(\bar e_n)⊗e_n$$ and the $K(\bar e_n)⊗e_n$s are pairwise orthogonal, hence
$$\|k\|_2^2=\sum\|K(\bar e_n)\otimes e_n\|_{L^2(A^2)}^2=\sum\|K(\bar e_n)\|_{L^2(A)}^2=:\|K\|_{HS}^2.$$